# TS Project - Cannot find module

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a typescript project with a tsconfig.json and all the node module imports have the error **Cannot find module**.  What am I missing?  The appropriate module is installed in the node_modules folder, and executing tsc works properly

Example import: `import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';`

tsconfig.json:

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "experimentalAsyncFunctions": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by removing the following line from my tsconfig.json.  The tsc CLI tipped me off that it was a problem.

`"experimentalAsyncFunctions": true,`

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your folder structure to verify that you are setup correctly.

What you seem to be missing is the tsd file for angular2.

`npm install -g tsd
tsd query angular2 --action install`

Check out the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs#_great-code-editing-experiences) for more info.